# intersection of two array of objects basis on the value

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have two arrays like this:

1. [{
   id: 123,
   refNo: "q1w2e3",
   transactionName: "poke"
   },
   {
   id: 143,
   refNo: "w3e4r5",
   transactionName: "mon"
   }]
2. [
     {
       id: 456,
       refNo: "q1w2e3",
       rating: 5
     },
     {
       id: 967,
       refNo: "w3e4r5",
       rating: 3.5
     }
   ]

I want to merge them basis on the refNo. The resulting array would look like:

```
[
  {
    id: 456,
    refNo: "q1w2e3",
    transactionName: "poke",
    rating: 5
  },
  {
    id: 967,
    refNo: "w3e4r5",
    transactionName: "mon",
    rating: 3.5
  }
]
```

It will be a one to one mapping. No duplicate refNo will be present in both the arrays.

Comment: Are not the `id` properties colliding here? Which one you want to keep in the merged object?

Comment: What is the algorithm for merging when both objects you are merging have  conflicting properties?  For example, how did you pick `id: 456` instead of `id: 123`?

Comment: Array 1 will merge in Array 2 keeping id of Array 2 as it is, removing Array 1's id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go with something like:

```
var arrayA = [{ id: 123, refNo: "q1w2e3", transactionName: "poke" }, { id: 143, refNo: "w3e4r5", transactionName: "mon" }];
var arrayB = [ { id: 456, refNo: "q1w2e3", rating: 5 }, { id: 967, refNo: "w3e4r5", rating: 3.5 } ];

var result = arrayA.map(function(itemA){
    var itemB = _.find(arrayB, function(x){
        return itemA.refNo === x.refNo;
    });

    return _.merge(itemA, itemB);
});
```

** Assumed that if same properties exist in both items - the item from second array will win in merge. Merge is from lodash. [lodash#merge](https://lodash.com/docs#merge)

Comment: There's a problem here. The result that I get is itemB and not the combined array.

Comment: No, it is actually itemA extended by itemB

Comment: For some reasons extend is not working. I tried loadash and used `merge`. It works then.

Comment: Strange.. By the way, `extend` will work with lodash as well

Answer (score 2):

Do it with **[`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)** , **[`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** and **[`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** methods

```js
var arr1 = [{
  id: 123,
  refNo: "q1w2e3",
  transactionName: "poke"
}, {
  id: 143,
  refNo: "w3e4r5",
  transactionName: "mon"
}];
arr2 = [{
  id: 456,
  refNo: "q1w2e3",
  rating: 5
}, {
  id: 967,
  refNo: "w3e4r5",
  rating: 3.5
}];

var arr3 = arr2
  // iterate over `arr2` and generate array
  // based on the it's element
  .map(function(v) {
    // create a new object and assign properties of both 
    // array object with same `refNo` property
    return Object.assign({},
      // find the object with same `refNo` property
      arr1.find(function(v1) {
        // set the condition for find
        return v1.refNo === v.refNo;
        // set `v` for extending object property
      }), v)
  })

console.log(arr3);
```

Comment: I am getting data in this form `[
    {
        "$__": {
            "strictMode": false,
            "getters": {},
            "wasPopulated": false,
            "activePaths": {
                "paths": {`
What exactly is it?

Comment: @phantomphoenix : which browser?

Comment: I am getting data from mongoose model.

Comment: @phantomphoenix : I think you are using nodejs..... use polyfill options for method from the mdn docs.... also refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31632569/configure-node-to-use-object-assign

Answer (score 1):

This might help. Added some comments to explain the steps.

```js
var arr1 = [{ id: 123, refNo: "q1w2e3", transactionName: "poke" }, { id: 143, refNo: "w3e4r5", transactionName: "mon" }];
var arr2 = [ { id: 456, refNo: "q1w2e3", rating: 5 }, { id: 967, refNo: "w3e4r5", rating: 3.5 } ];
var resultArray = [];

for (var i = 0, len = arr2.length; i < len; i++) {
  // find in other array by 'refNo'
  var findByRef = arr1.filter(function(v) {
    return v.refNo === arr2[i].refNo; // Filter out the appropriate one
  });

  // merge result
  var merged = merge_options(findByRef[0], arr2[i]);
  // add merged to result array
  resultArray.push(merged);
}
// dump result array
console.log(resultArray);

// merge all attrs of two objects
function merge_options(obj1,obj2){
    var obj3 = {};
    for (var attrname in obj1) { obj3[attrname] = obj1[attrname]; }
    for (var attrname in obj2) { obj3[attrname] = obj2[attrname]; }
    return obj3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

```js
var array1  = [{ id: 123, refNo: "q1w2e3", transactionName: "poke" }, { id: 143, refNo: "w3e4r5", transactionName: "mon" }];

var array2 = [ { id: 456, refNo: "q1w2e3", rating: 5 }, { id: 967, refNo: "w3e4r5", rating: 3.5 } ];


for(var i = 0 ; i < array1.length ; i++) {
 var tempRef = array1[i]['refNo'];
  
  for(var j = 0 ; j < array2.length ; j ++) {
   if(array2[j]['refNo'] === tempRef) {
     array1[i]['rating'] = array2[j]['rating'];
    }
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(array1));
```

Answer (score 0):

To reduce the time needed to loop over all of the items from O(n^2) to O(n), you can use an object whose keys are `refNo`s.

Something like this:

```
var uniqueRefNos = {};

var array1 = [ { id: 123, refNo: "q1w2e3", transactionName: "poke" }, { id: 143, refNo: "w3e4r5", transactionName: "mon" } ];
var array2 = [ { id: 456, refNo: "q1w2e3", rating: 5 }, { id: 967, refNo: "w3e4r5", rating: 3.5 } ];

for(var i = 0 ; i < array1.length ; i++){
    //add all objects in array1 to uniqueRefNos
    uniqueRefNos[array1[i].refNo] = array1[i];
}

for(var i = 0 ; i < array2.length ; i++){
    //check if key already exists
    var key = array2[i].refNo;
    if (uniqueRefNos.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      //if it does add the remaining attributes replacing the previous values from array1
      for (var key2 in array2[i]) {
        if(array2[i].hasOwnProperty(key2)) {
          uniqueRefNos[key][key2] = array2[i][key2];
        }
      }
    } else {
        //if key doesn't exist add the whole object
        uniqueRefNos[array2[i].refNo] = array2[i];
    }
}
```

This will put all your inner objects inside one object which you can loop over and dump into another array using:

```
var finalArray = [];
for (var key in uniqueRefNos) {
  if (uniqueRefNos.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    finalArray.push(uniqueRefNos[key]);
  }
}
```